# .last.removeClass() on recently double clicked element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this program that allows the user to edit a div when the user double clicks it. I'm trying to only make the most recent double clicked div have a border. I'm doing this right now with the addClass method, I add the .selceted class with this function:

```
$(function () {
$("div").dblclick(function (e) {
    clickedTD = event.target;
    $(clickedTD).find(clickedTD).last.removeClass("selected").addClass("selected"); 
}
```

I'm trying to make the last selected div be deleted with this `.find(clickedTD).last.removeClass("selected")`
So that most recent double clicked div is the only one with the .selected class. But this didn't work and I'm unsure why.

**Here is my full code:**

```js
var text;
var selectedText;

var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
var blue2 = document.getElementById("blue2");



var elementCounter = 0;
function addElement() { 
  var classN = event.target.id;

 text = document.getElementById("input").value;

  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

  newDiv.id = 'temp'+elementCounter;
  newDiv.classList = "div";
  elementCounter++

  if (classN == "blue"){
    newDiv.classList = "blue"
      } else if (classN == "red"){
        newDiv.classList = "red"
      } else if (classN == "green"){
        newDiv.classList = "green"
      } else if (classN == "blue2"){
        newDiv.classList = "blue2"
      }

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    
    var currentlyDragged;
 
    $("div").draggable({
     drag: function (e) {
         currentlyDragged = e.target.id
         selectedText = event.target;
         text = $(selectedText).html();     
    }
    });

$(function () {
    $("div").dblclick(function (e) {
        clickedTD = event.target;
        $(clickedTD).find(clickedTD).last.removeClass("selected").addClass("selected"); 

    }

    );
});

  });
  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap');
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

// Add all icons to the library so you can use it in your page
library.add(fas, far, fab)


h1, body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


.selected {
  border-style: dashed;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 150px;
    height: 30px;

  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
}

divWhite {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  color: #fff;
}

.blue {
  background: linear-gradient(87deg, #5e72e4 0, #825ee4 100%);
  color: white;
}

.red {
  background: linear-gradient(87deg, #f5365c 0, #f56036 100%);
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background: linear-gradient(87deg, #2dce89 0, #2dcecc 100%);
  color: white;
}


.blue2 {
  background: linear-gradient(87deg, #11cdef 0, #1171ef 100%);
  color: white;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  color: white;
}


button{
    font-size: .875rem; 
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 90px;

    text-align: center;

    position: relative;

    transition: all .15s ease;
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    will-change: transform;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  


  </head>
  <body style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">


<body id="container">    

<header id="inputAssignments">    
<h1 id="mulAsi">Input Your Assignments for the week:</h1>
<h1 style="display:none" id="oneAsi">Input Your Assignment:</h1>


    <input id="input" type="text" value="text">
    <button class="blue" id="blue" onclick="addElement()" >Make it Purple</button> 
    <button class="red" id="red" onclick="addElement()" >Make it Red</button> 
    <button class="green" id="green" onclick="addElement()" >Make it Green</button> 
    <button class="blue2" id="blue2" onclick="addElement()" >Make it Blue</button> 


    <button style="display:none" id="blue2" onclick="addElement();" >input</button> 

    <h1 height="30px"></h1>

</header>





</header>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `removeClass("selected").addClass("selected")` - what's the point?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I'm trying to remove the class from the last double clicked div: does this not work: `$(clickedTD).find(clickedTD).last.removeClass("selected")`

Comment: You should be getting an error in the console. It's `.last()`, not `.last`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is ...

> `div` dbclick

1. Remove `selected class` from `div` (actually... `div.selcted`)
2. Add `selected class` to `div` what you dbclicked.

> `input[type=text]` change

1. set `input[type=text].value` to `div.selcted.innerHTML`

When you use jQuery event,

there are two ways to get `$this`

Let me show you how to solve this problem.

1. Regular Function

   ```
    $('#elementId').on('click', function(){
        //1. Remove selected class from div
        $('div.selected').removeClass('selected');

        //2. Add selected class to $this
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('selected')
    });
   ```
2. Arrow Function

   ```
    $('#elementId').on('click', (_event) => {
        //1. Remove selected class from div
        $('div.selected').removeClass('selected');

        //2. Add selected class to $this
        const $this = $(_event.currentTarget); // important!
        $this.addClass('selected')
    });
   ```

Finally, Change event of input[type=text]

I will skip arrow function this time.

```
$('#someInput').on('change', function(){
    const value = $(this).val();
    $('div.selcted').html(value);
});
```

DONE!

I recommend you to set id or class to your HTML DOM.

If you set event to ['div', 'input' ...], you will get side effect

Not use div, input

Use `#element001`(best) or `div.myElement001`

bye bye